# jooq liquibase generation with maven plugin. Getting resource not found

Tags: maven, liquibase, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I am trying to use the jooq code generation plugin to point to my liquibase change set. I am using the following plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.5</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta-extensions-liquibase</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.5</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jooq-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <generator>
            <database>
              <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase</name>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <key>scripts</key>
                  <value>src/main/resources/schemas/sql/changelog-root.xml</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </database>
            <generate>
              <daos>true</daos>
              <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
            </generate>
          </generator>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

However I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.15.5:generate (jooq-generate) on project cas: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Error while exporting schema: src/main/resources/schemas/sql/changelog-root.xml does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

The file does exist at the location specified but the plugin can't seem to find it.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Have you reviewed jOOQ's manual about [Code Generation from Liquibase](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will be useful to others.
This was a bug in jooq which is now fixed

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12872